# Tamper monkey not clicking

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

HTML:

```
<div id="someid">Attack ..</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#someid").click(function() {
    alert("I was clicked.");
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgJKU/

Greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://jsfiddle.net/kgJKU/
// ==/UserScript==
$("#someid").trigger('click');
```

... but I don't know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ("HTMLEvents");
    clickEvent.initEvent ("click", true, true);
    $("#someid")[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

});
```

This is how it works in Firefox/Greasemonkey. However it does not seem to work on jsfiddle.net, but it should work on all other websites.

Make sure your script uses the same jquery version as the website uses.